# How to find exact configuration date of android phone by user?

Tags: android, configuration, operating-system

I am writing app to show user about his phone history. So I m trying to find exact date of configuration by user (When he purchased or Configured by email id) not by manufacturer.

Is their any possibilities. I am googling but don't know it is possible or not?

Comment: Whats is wrong in this question ?? I thought world class developers are on this forum, might give some suggestion about this?? But without any justification people are giving negative mark??

Comment: I am also searching similar kind of thing. Please let me know if you get any clue.